# Окрашено и покрашено, и неправильно

Tags: лексика

Как правильно? "Стена уже окрашена" или "покрашена"? Отличаются ли эти глаголы смыслом?

Comment: Предложение "Стена уже окрашена." совпадает по смыслу с предложением "Стена уже покрашена.".

Вместе с тем, предложение "Стена уже окрашена." короче, чем предложение "Стена уже покрашена.".

Из изложенного следует, что предложение "Стена уже окрашена." лаконичнее, чем предложение "Стена уже покрашена.".

Answer (score 6):

Правильно: стена уже  ОКРАШЕНА, пол ОКРАШЕН. ПОКРАСИТЬ - разг.

Comment: "Покрасить" относит к разговорным только Кузнецов, что уже делает трактовку сомнительной.

Comment: Почему же только Кузнецов? Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук под 
 ред. В. В. Лопатина относит "покрасить" к разг. Кстати, этот словарь взят за основу на портале "Грамота.ру".

Comment: Ссылочку можно, где бы у Лопатина ["покрасить"][1] считался разговорным?

Насчет "взят за основу" даже не пытаюсь понять. За основу чего?

[1]: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%EE%EA%F0%E0%F1%E8%F2%FC&all=x

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%EE%EA%F0%E0%F1%E8%F2%FC&all=x. Я не думаю, что Вы не поняли мой комментарий. Не беритесь за старое, не цепляйтесь к словам. Ваши высказывания умны, но не всегда правильны. Не навязывайте свои ответы  другим. Задающий вопрос в состоянии разобраться в ответах.

Comment: Уважаемая Соан!   
1. Я думаю, что Вы не поняли моего. Я никогда не переспрашиваю ради переспросить.  
2. Пожалуйста, не переходите на личности и не учите меня, как надо отвечать на те или иные вопросы. Я не вступаю и впредь не буду вступать в такую полемику. Здешняя модерация не позволяет.   
3. Вы не привели ссылку на Лопатина, Ваше утверждение о том, что у Лопатина что-то такое есть, недостоверно.  
4. На вопрос "за основу чего?" Вы, увы, не ответили, он для меня действительно интересен. Структуру словаря на Грамоте я хорошо знаю, ибо в некотором смысле принимал участие в её разработке.

Comment: 1.Пожалуйста, давайте прекратим наш спор. Продолжения дискуссии я не хочу.Наш "диалог" мне напоминает героев сказки, действие которой происходит на мосточке. Р.S. Если я найду одно интервью, я смогу Вам ответить на 4-й пункт Вашего комментария.

Comment: Можете не искать. Я всего лишь хотел понять, что именно Вы вкладывали в употреблённою Вами фразу. Если для этого надо искать какое-то "интервью"...
Что такое "мосточек" я уже просто боюсь переспрашивать. Просто скажу, что мне этот термин столь же неизвестен и непонятен.
Если вы о сказке Барто, то простите, я себя таковым не считаю. Они дорогу делили, а мне делить с Вами нечего.

Comment: История, кстати, глуповатая изначально. Автор явно не видел баранов иначе как в виде шашлыков. Живые бараны навстречу друг другу не ходят. И если черный шел утром домой(?!), то куда шел его "белый брат"? А бодаются исключительно в период размножения.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, в современном языке "покрасить" вполне допустимо без ограничения применения. Более того, вытесняет некогда строго нормативное "окрасить".

PS Я даже засомневался в том, что "окрасить" было единственным нормативным. Ожегов даёт "покрасить" как единственную видовую пару к "красить", у Ушакова тоже нет пометы...

Вот "покрашено" - это да, можно принять за разговорный вариант к "окрашено". Только это, пардон, не глаголы.

Comment: Причастие - глагол или нет - спорный вопрос. Как раз  словари отражают точку зрения,  что причастие - форма глагола. Причастия не даны в отдельных словарных статьях. Поэтому стилистические пометы относятся ко все формам. 

Например,

ПОКРА́СИТЬ -кра́шу, -кра́сишь; покра́шенный; -шен, -а, -о; св. 1. что. Разг. Окрасить, выкрасить. П. дом, крышу, забор. П. шерсть в синий цвет. П. почти бесцветным лаком. П. волосы. П. (какой-л.) краской, тушью, помадой. 2. (что). -  Большой толковый словарь русского языка.

Comment: Хотя мне тоже глагол покрасить кажется вполне нейтральным, а вот окрасить носит некий оттенок книжности. Но это мое личное восприятие. Ориентироваться надо все-таки на академические словари.

Comment: Ларf, я не о том, глагол - это причастие или нет. И конечно же не о личном мнении того или иного форумчанинина. Во всей это истории мне категорически не нравится только безапелляционность утверждения, что "покрасить" (именно глагол!) является разговорным вариантом (Кузнецов в подобных вопросах явно не спец, да и словарь его толковый, никак не орфоэпический). Ну и, конечно же, ничем не подтвержденная ссылка на Лопатина. Ну нельзя ж на него всех собак вешать просто потому, что он - Лопатин. Давайте все-таки не приписывать ему то, чего он не говорил. Или ссылку давать.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что эти два слова равноправны в литературном языке, но употребление их все-таки отличается. Например, вы же не скажете "закан ПОКРАСИЛ лес багрянцем"))) А вот "окрасил" — запросто.
То есть, "покрасить" относится непосредственно к работе с краской, а вот "окрасить" — понятие более широкое.

Comment: Если употребление различается, наверное, неравноправны, а равнодопустимы, равнонормативны... Нет?
Различия в употреблении безусловно есть, это естественно, абсолютных синонимов в языке не бывает. Но различие тут, имхо, другого плана. Окрасить - не обязательно выкрасить полностью. Покрасить - это от и д, дез недокраса. Как-то так.

Comment: Cел  на  свежевыкрашенную  скамейку - испачкался.  Покрасить, выкрасить,  закрасить  -  работа  с  краской.  Окрасить - понятие  более  широкое,  правильно.  Но  скорее  связано  с  изменением  оттенка,  тона,  цвета  предметов.  Ззкат, солнце,  линяющая  ткань -  окрашивают.

Comment: Считаю  оба  слова  литературными.

Answer (score 1):

На такие вопросы лучше отвечать примерами. Вот, например, интересно: Том Сойер *покрасил* забор или *окрасил* забор? Ещё интереснее: ввожу в Яндексе фразу "окрасить скамейку" - и что, как вы думаете, получаю в ответ? Яндекс вообще не знает такого словосочетания! :-)

> В выдачу добавлены ответы по запросу
> «покрасить скамейку».
>
> Искать только «окрасить скамейку»?

Comment: Я думаю, анекдот не повредит?
Археолог начинает копать на Куликовом поле и находит ржавую табличку, буквы с трудом угадываются : "Осторожно, покрошено"...

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю  на   прямой  вопрос:  отличаются  ли  глаголы  "окрасить"  и  "покрасить"  смыслом ?  Ответ  тоже  прямой  -  отличаются.  Например,  Том  покрасил  забор  белой  краской, вечернее  солнце  окрасило  его  в  розовый  цвет.

Answer (score 0):

Как раз читаю дочкам "Тома Сойера", специально вернулась к началу и перечитала. Том "белил забор", его приятели - тоже. Нигде не встретила окрасил/покрасил. Зато целый ряд синонимичных конструкций:  "окунул кисть в ведро и ПРОВЕЛ ею ПО верхней ДОСКЕ забора", "взялся за кисть и ПРОДОЛЖАЛ не торопясь РАБОТАТЬ",  "ПРОВЕЛ КИСТЬЮ по забору", "ВОДИЛ КИСТЬЮ взад и вперед", "ДОБАВЛЯЛ МАЗОК, другой", в одном месте нашла "покрасить". Но это речь Тома: "... Джиму тоже хотелось покрасить...". Хотелось окрасить - не звучит, на мой взгляд, совершенно).

Comment: @Надюшка, речь не о "каноническом" тексте (тем более - переводном), а о самой ситуации, как она нами воспринимается: как бы вы сказали о Томе Сойере? Или о каком-нибудь Карлсоне? - и мы видим, что "окрасить" здесь никак невозможно, язык не поворачивается.

"Джиму тоже хотелось покрасить" - здесь, возможно, не совсем то значение (="некоторое время красить").

Comment: >Как раз читаю дочкам "Тома Сойера"... 
  
И какие выводы? Я вижу, например, то, что здесь почти нет глаголов совершенного вида. (Кроме "провел" - но оно в несколько другом значении.) Откуда тогда взяться "покрасить"?

Comment: Согласна, что не ответила на вопрос. Я просто поделилась наблюдениями. Понравилось, что в тексте (пусть и переводном) слова "белил/ красил; побелил/покрасил" почти не встречаются.

Answer (score 0):

Вот представим деталь авто. Если деталь окрашеваемая то стало быть её окрашевают. Тогда процесс окраски можно назвать окрас или нет ?

Comment: Нет.  Окрас - это  масть  животного.  Может,  что-то  и  окрашивают,  но  окрашЕвать  что-либо  нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Красить - покрасить, выкрасить, окрасить, а также прокрасить, закрасить, перекрасить.

За смысл глагола отвечают приставки: ПО - нейтральное значение, используется для образования видовой пары: красить (несов.) - покрасить (сов.). Другие приставки придают дополнительные смысловые оттенки: ВЫ - завершенность, законченность, тщательность действия, О - полный охват предмета действием.

В словарях можно встретить: покрасить - разг., но мне это не кажется справедливым, здесь в каждом случае нужно решать индивидуально. Скамейку лучше окрасить (со всех сторон, а не только, например, сидение), а вот пол лучше  покрасить, чем окрасить (у него только одна сторона) или ВЫкрасить (окончательно и бесповоротно)в какую-нибудь новую краску.

Comment: Окрасить,  в  смысле  покрасить  со  всех  сторон,  всё  равно  звучит  как-то  искусственно,  если  это  какое-то  материальное  действие.

Comment: >О - полный охват предмета действием.   
  
Это не так. "Полный охват" - только одно из значений, в "окрасил" выступает другое - действие при контакте (примерно его трудно в двух словах сформулировать), сравните - ожечь (ожог), омыть, осыпать...  
Поэтому если вы сели в новом пальто на покрашенную/окрашенную скамейку, то вы окрасились, а не покрасились.

Comment: В толковом словаре Ефремовой "Окраситься" рассматривается в качестве примера с таким объяснением: покрыть или покрыться чем-либо с помощью действия,  названного мотивирующим глаголом, но это уже втрое значение приставки в этой статье. Первое - направить действие во все стороны (осмотреть, обглодать, ощупать).

Comment: Сев на скамейку, мы, скорее, просто испачкаемся в краске. Если же вы говорите, что "окрасились", то применяете к ситуации художественный прием гротеска, то есть явно ее  "приукрашиваете".

Answer (score 0):

> Первое - направить действие во все стороны (осмотреть, обглодать, ощупать).

У Вас прямо хобби - искать кто главнее и какое первое. Второе - не значит неправильное. 
Мне вот для подобных разговоров как-то без разницы, в каком порядке они в словаре даны. же что "окрашено" в большинстве случае не означает со всех сторон.

> Cев на скамейку, мы, скорее, просто испачкаемся в краске.

Или окрасимся. 
София, Вы опять хотите поспорить ни о чем. Можно кучу доводов привести, безусловно правильных - и не очень, но какое это все отношение имеет к заявленной теме?!

Comment: Сев  на  скамейку,  мы  испачкаемся.  Окрасимся  не  звучит.  Но  если  иностранец  так  скажет,  мы  поймём  его  правильно.

Comment: Надо же построить вертикаль. В словарях на первом месте указывается основное (центральное) значение  слова (морфемы), а далее - вторичные значения, то есть те же самые в основе, но получившие дополнительные смысловые оттенки.